# Will a CT scan help monitor my Tibia recovery better than an Xray?

Tags: bone-fractures, x-rays, ct-scans, tibia

I had an accident 18 months ago and can't use the leg fully because the Operation site hasn't healed and is still discharging. I had an IM surgery, and the implant has been removed about 10 months ago.

I have had several Xrays but I still feel we are not getting the real picture of what's going on, as the Xray is usually done on the front view and the side view for the leg. A family friend has suggested that a CT Scan will probably show more. Considering the cost involved, I dont know if that's the right thing to do.

Comment: Sorry but site rules prohibit us from offering personal medical advice. In any case, nobody on the internet can answer your question without actually examining you.